# No backup found on this account issue in WhatsApp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, restore, google-drive

By mistake, I deleted the local backup of WhatsApp.  But my Google Drive is showing I still have the latest backup which is of 24 Feb 2024.

But but the problem is when I reinstall WhatsApp and press restore from Drive, it shows "no backup found on this account".

How to restore backup from Google Drive?

Comment: How and where did you delete the backup?

Comment: Make sure you're using the same Google account and phone number.

Comment: I deleted the local files of whatsapp but I have a backup in Google drive .and yes I'm using same google account and phone number to restore and I also have tried lot of troubleshooting methods so please help me ...